# Are there proper Ad invariant sets on simple lie algebras?

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $\mathcal C\subset \mathfrak g$ be a subset in a Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ satisfying the following two conditions:

1. $\mathrm{Ad}(G)\mathcal C=\mathcal C$
2. If $X,Y\in \mathcal C$, then $X+Y\in\mathcal C$ or $X-Y\in\mathcal C$.

(one can also assume 3. There is a proper subspace $\mathcal H\subset \mathfrak g$ such that $\mathcal H\subset \mathcal C$)

Is it true that $\mathcal C=\mathfrak g$?

By $\mathrm{Ad}$ I mean the map induced by the derivative of the conjugation at the identity on a Lie group.

Comment: So you are assuming that this is the Lie algebra of some fixed Lie group? And I assume you work over $\mathbb{C}$? Or maybe $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Yes. It is the algebra of a (real) Lie group. Thank you.

Comment: Also, what is that thing that $Ad(G)\mathcal{C}$ is supposed to equal?

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Just corrected it. I was not finding the edit button (pardon, I am new here.)

Comment: I think you will need to assume the Lie algebra to be simple rather than just semisimple for this (I think if you take a product of Lie groups to start with, the one of the factors should provide a factor of the Lie algebra and this should be an example where it fails).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: Indeed.

Comment: Stupid observation:  $\mathcal{C} = \{0\}$, it satisfies $1.$ and $2.$, so you really do want something like $3.$  Also, $\mathfrak{g}\setminus\{0\}$ satisfies $1.$ and $2.$

Comment: "a proper subspace": do you mean a nonzero subspace? In "proper subspace $V\subset W$", proper means $V\neq W$.

Comment: @YCor A nontrivial subspace of $\mathfrak g $: neither $\{0\} $ (which would not help) nor $\mathfrak g $ (where the result would be trivial)

Comment: I understood what you mean, I just mean it's confusing as it not the usual meaning (and "nonzero" has a clear meaning and is enough here)